# How can I set Zend DateTime Element to '0000-00-00 00:00:00'?

Tags: php, date, datetime, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am using the Zend Framework 2 DateTimeSelect.  How can I set the value (either in the form class or controller) to '0000-00-00 00:00:00'?  Currently it defaults to the end of the year.  I get the following results when i try the following in the controller...

```
$date = date("0-0-0 0:0:0"); `This gives me the date as November 30th`
$date =  '0000-00-00 00:00:00';`This gives me the date as November 30th`
$date =  NULL; `This gives me the current date time.` 

 $form->get('datetime')->setValue($date);
```

I would like to leave this field either empty or as 0 until the task is complete.

Many Thanks
Matt

Comment: why dont u use a empty option?

Comment: How do I do this?'empty_option'=>'0-0-0 0:0:0' gives me todays date and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a misconception as to how years are counted arround the 1 b.c and 1 a.d mark.

The last day month and year of before christus is 30th of december 1 b.c. Right after that follows the 1st January 1 a.d(Anno Domini). Historically speaking there is no year 0 it start's with year one.

Which means if we create DateTime Object and set a date to day=0, month=0, year=0 will still be in the before christus date region.

```
$test = new DateTime();
$test->setDate(0, 0, 0);
//I left out timezone settings so it'll take the default timezone
var_dump($test); exit;
```

would outup:

> object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(20) "-0001-11-30 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" }

```
-0001-11-30 looks a bit weird since php counts months beginning with 0 = January, .... , 11 = December.
```

Now unlike the setDate method the constructor takes strings as a parameter which gets parsed into the Time Object. Which basically calls the set Date method at the end with the same

> day = 0
>   month = 0
>   year = 0

which again would output:

> object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(20) "-0001-11-30 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Berlin" }

This leads me to the conclusion that getting the out of the box DateTime Object Class to render the specific date "0000-00-00:00:00:00" is literary impossible and historically incorrect.

Could you please elaborate as to why you want to this in detail?

Comment: The user if filling out a form with a submit and complete date.  The submit date defaults to todays date.  The complete date will be edited once the task is complete (maybe a few days after the submission).  Ideally the value would be null or 0 until complete.  As a work around I could populate it with a bogus date in the past and know that these are incomplete (there is also a status on the form of complete, submitted, and in progress).  I appreciate your through explanation.

Comment: would it not be better to have 2 fields in your database one that has the submited value and the other one being completed? That way you could track completed ones with just a query?

Comment: this is what I currently have submitted_date_field and completed_date_field.

Comment: well within your persistane you'll only have to set the field to null. It has to be nullable within your database table thou. Just dont build the completed datefield if its the initial creation of the entry i.e first time form submit.